# How to use cmake to find the boost pool library?

Tags: linux, cmake, boost-pool

I've installed boost like this on Ubuntu 14.04:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev libboost-dev
```

If I have the following in my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
SET ( Boost_DEBUG               1   )
SET ( Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS     ON  )
SET ( Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED   ON  )
SET ( Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME  ON  )
FIND_PACKAGE ( Boost COMPONENTS log regex pool date_time REQUIRED )
```

Cmake has no problem finding other boost libraries, but it cannot find `pool`.  I get the following:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1131 (message):
Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.
Boost version: 1.54.0
Boost include path: /usr/include
Could not find the following static Boost libraries:
    boost_pool
```

I can see the files are where they should be, along with the rest of the boost includes:

```
> locate pool/pool.hpp
/usr/include/boost/pool/pool.hpp
```

Is there a bug in cmake 2.8.12 where it expects pool (a header-only library) to have a .a or .so file, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Boost.Pool is header-only, you shouldn't list it in the `find_package` call.

If the `find_package(Boost ...)` call succeeds, it will have located the path to the Boost includes, and this will mean Boost.Pool will automatically be available just by adding `${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}` to a [`target_include_directories`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3atarget_include_directories) or [`include_directories`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3ainclude_directories) call.